# Combination of Keypreview property and Keypress Event In Winform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keypress, keydown, onkeyup

As far as I know that  above  is not possible in below case. I explain it in details here.

Suppose If I have **Form1** and I set it’s **Keypreview Property = true** than the

**“Keyprees,Keydown,and Keyup"** Events are only works for winform not for their child

objects/components  Like **“textbox”,”ListBox”** etc.

So my question is  :- **Is there possibility to works  it for winforms and it’s child controls.?**

**Is it possible for both forms and controls by setting form1's keypreview property to true?**

```
                               Or By Any Other Way
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you set that property to true you will still be able to catch the events for the child controls but you will also be able to catch a 'preview' event on the form and this basically gives you the oprtunity to handle the event before the platform forwards it to the child control.

The [MSDN explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) is conclusive.

Comment: @Liviu M, suggested link shows received keystroke only for forms not for child controls

Comment: That is the example. You must not set the e.Handled property to true in order for the event to propagate.

Comment: @Liviu, Do u mean If i set e.handle property to true for form1_Keydown Eventhandler than it's works for textbox1_Keypress eventhandler?

Comment: No. You must set it to false for the key event to be caught by the textbox1. If you set it to true you are basically saying that "I have handled the event, don't forward it".

Comment: @Liviu, That's the question is. If I set keypreview property to true for form1. than I will handle Keypress/keydown/and keyup event for form1. but it's not work with textbox/listbox. is it possible by anyother way. is there solution for that?

Comment: I can;t make it any more clear than this: "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the form will receive key events before the event is passed to the control that has focus." (MSDN). If your textbox had focus while you pressed the key then if the e.Handled property is set to false the event on the textbox should have been raise. If in your case it doesn't then you have some other problem and it will be very helpfull to post your code until now.

Comment: @Liviu, Yes You are right there is coding mistake in my application

Comment: Happy we sort it out eventually :)